# Poor performance processing a pair RDD with very skewed data

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a pair RDD with millions of key-value pairs, where every value is a list which may contain a single element or billions of elements. This leads to a poor performance since the large groups will block the nodes of the cluster for hours, while groups that would take a few seconds cannot be processed in parallel since the whole cluster is already busy.

Is there anyway to improve this?

**EDIT:**

The operation that is giving me problems is a `flatMap` where the whole list for a given key is analyzed. The key is not touched, and the operation compares every element in the list to the rest of the list, which takes a huge amount of time but unfortunately it has to be done. This means that the WHOLE list needs to be in the same node at the same time. The resulting RDD will contain a sublist depending on a value calculated in the `flatMap`.

I cannot use broadcast variables in this case scenario, as no common data will be used between the different key-value pairs. As for a partitioner, according to the O'Reilly Learning Spark book, this kind of operation will not benefit from a partitioner since no shuffle is involved (although I am not sure if this is true). Can a partitioner help in this situation?

**SECOND EDIT:**

This is an example of my code:

```
public class MyFunction implements FlatMapFunction
    <Tuple2<String, Iterable<Bean>>, ComparedPerson>  {


public Iterable<ProcessedBean> call(Tuple2<Key, Iterable<Bean>> input) throws Exception {
    List<ProcessedBean> output = new ArrayList<ProcessedBean>();
    List<Bean> listToProcess = CollectionsUtil.makeList(input._2());

    // In some cases size == 2, in others size > 100.000
    for (int i = 0; i < listToProcess.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < listToProcess.size(); j++) {
            ProcessedBean processed = processData(listToProcess.get(i), listToProcess.get(j));

            if (processed != null) {
                output.add(processed);
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

The double for will loop `n(n-1)/2` times, but this cannot be avoided.

Comment: you could try flatmapping the  (k,longValueSeq) => Seq[(k,singleV]) where further processing will be uniform.

Comment: could you add the code to the question? After reading your edit, it sounds like there could be other options to achieve the same.

Comment: What does `processData` do? You got some answers on how to distribute the work on the cluster, but I'd be more interested in figuring out how to flatten this O(n^2) loop to make things more efficient, or at least, how to break the data in smaller pieces that can be efficiently parallelized.

Comment: I am comparing arrays of Strings.

Comment: Comparing them for what? The output of processData is apparently optional, and if it's null, you drop the result. Perhaps this part can be optimized?

Comment: @DPM exactly my thoughts.  Even if comparison is required, maybe some specialized structures could speed up the process. But it all depends on the specific logic required.

Comment: I cannot say why I need to compare them, but it is not optional. If the result does not meet some requirements, the result is dropped (it returns null). I am currently working in improving the `processData` part, even writing some routines in C and Assembly, but I also need to be able to parallelize the data a little bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'processData' is expensive, it's possible that you could parallelize that step and pick up some gains there.

In pseudo-code, it would be something like:

```
def processData(bean1:Bean, bean2:Bean):Option[ProcessedData] = { ... }

val rdd:RDD[(Key, List[Bean])] = ...

val pairs:RDD[(Bean, Bean)] = rdd.flatMap((key, beans) => {
    val output = mutable.List[ProcessedBean]()
    val len = beans.length
    for (var i=0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        for (var j=i+1; j < len; j++) {
            output.add((beans(i), beans(j)))
        }
    }
    output
}).repartition(someNumber)

val result:RDD[ProcessedBean] = pairs
    .map(beans => processData(beans._1, beans._2))
    .filter(_.isDefined)
    .map(_.get)
```

The flatMap step will still be bounded by your biggest list, and you'll incur a shuffle when you repartition, but moving the processData step outside of that N^2 step could gain you some parallelism.

Comment: This could work, since the `processData` step is really expensive. However, if I create a new RDD with all of the pairs, the size of this RDD could be way too huge...

Answer (score 4):

The order in which the keys get processed has no effect on the total computation time. The only issue from variance (some values are small, others are large) I can imagine is at the end of processing: one large task is still running while all other nodes are already finished.

If this is what you are seeing, you could try increasing the number of partitions. This would reduce the size of tasks, so a super large task at the end is less likely.

Broadcast variables and partitioners will not help with the performance. I think you should focus on making the everything-to-everything comparison step as efficient as possible. (Or better yet, avoid it. I don't think quadratic algorithms are really sustainable in big data.)

Comment: What you have just described is exactly our main issue. Do you recommend using `repartition` or `coalesce`?

Comment: Doesn't matter: `repartition` just calls `coalesce` :) (see [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c94d0626471e209ab7ebfc588f9a2992946b7ed5/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L330)) It's best if you can avoid `repartition`/`coalesce` and build the RDD with a higher partition count from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Skew like this is often domain specific. You could create your value data as an RDD and join on it. Or you could try using broadcast variables. Or you could write a custom partitioner that might help split the data differently.

But, ultimately, it is going to depend on the computation and specifics of the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the second approach will not work in my case. As for the first one, I am not sure about what you mean, and I am not sure about how to use a partitioner in this case. Please see my edit.